# Minecraft functions time.sleep

Tags: minecraft

Is there a way to put a time.sleep in a minecraft function for Minecraft bedrock like in python?
For example:

```
/say this is a test!
time.sleep(5)
/say This is executed after the time.sleep
```

Comment: I believe you would have to use a game modification or plugin to execute python functions from inside the game.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what a minecraft function is.

I assume you are using Minecraft: Java edition, to add delays in java you can use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`

`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` Sleeps for one second.

`TimeUnit.MINUTE.sleep(1);` Sleeps for one minute.

Comment: As stated in my question I play minecraft Bedrock, sorry for this on my end. I should have made this more clear. For minecraft functions see: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Function_(Bedrock_Edition)

Comment: I am going to point you to some resources that I found, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQ86XmVFX3E and https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/e99fxx/so_just_to_confirm_theres_no_way_to_delay_or/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a sleep function but not how you tried to do it. I made a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JdS1gnMHwJckBmFxDKa71F6qgykdFcfJ/view?usp=sharing) for you to explain what I mean.

1. Give yourself a command block:

   ```
   /give @s command_block
   ```
2. Place it and put your command into the window.
3. Place a command block next to it and put your second command in the window.
4. Change the presets to repeating always active and conditional.
5. Put the tick value in the last box. 20 ticks are equal to 1 second.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that runs every tick (can use repeat command block), and chain these commands to count seconds:

1. scoreboard players add timer1 {timer scoreboard name} 1
2. execute if score timer1 {timer scoreboard name} matches 20 run scoreboard players add timer2 1
3. scoreboard players set timer1 {timer scoreboard name} 0

Using these you can for five seconds using the same method:

1. execute if score timer2 {timer scoreboard name} matches 5 run {command of choice}
2. scoreboard players set timer2 {timer scoreboard name} 0

If you don't run these consecutively in a function, make sure to set them up in a chain command block after a repeat command block.

Answer (score -1):

Use hopper clocks for timings, works as a charm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).